# 'senderID’ is Missing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I am trying to create a pushnotification project using phonegap in ionic 3 and Iam using the source code provided in the Ionic Documentation for the phonegap-push- plugin. I am keep receiving an error for a specific constant in the source code that I found online, the source code is the following:

```
 const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {},
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {},
      browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
      }
    };
```

The error i am getting is for the cost options, when i hover my mouse on the option i am getting the following error

[image]

The code I am using is exactly the same as in the documentation but i don’t understand why is not working for me

Does anyone knows how can i fix this?

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

According to Ionic [documentation for android options](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/#AndroidPushOptions), there is one required param : `senderID`

This `senderID` correspond to your project number in the  Google Developer Console